# How to use Schedule module with a conditional while loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements, schedule

I'm trying to use the Schedule module to run a task during specific days of the week and specific hours, basically business hours. The while loop will work when the condition is true but once it's false it will not run again to see if the time frame still applies. I would have to restart the script for it to work.

I'm pretty new to Python and self taught. This is my first time posting here so please correct me if I've formatted this badly or haven't included enough information. I've tried scouring the forums to get around this particular issue I'm having but haven't found an answer; I'm probably searching wrong. It may be a simple issue but I've been wracking my brain for a few days. This is a small test portion of code that I'm trying to use for another script. Other people have recommended Cron but since this is going into a larger script, I only need a section of it to run on a task and not the whole thing.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import schedule
import time

def weekdayJob(x, i=None):
    week = dt.today().weekday()
    if i is not None and week < 5 and dt.now().hour in range(9,17):
        schedule.every(i).minutes.do(x)

def printJob():
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
    print(f"test {timestamp}\n")


weekdayJob(printJob, 5)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(5)
```

I've also tried

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import schedule
import time

def weekdayJob(x, i=None):
    week = dt.today().weekday()
    if i is not None and week < 5 and dt.now().hour in range(9,17):
        schedule.every(i).minutes.do(x)

def printJob():
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
    print(f"test {timestamp}\n")

x = 1
while x == 1:
    weekdayJob(printJob, 1)
    time.sleep(5)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(5)
```

I figured that putting the scheduled job in the while loop would make it constantly check to see if the conditional statement was true but that doesn't seem the case. How would I make it so this script is constantly checking if weekdayJob is within the desired time frame so I don't have to restart the script.

Answer (score 3):

Move the conditional statement into the printjob function, and do not use nested while loop (code here switches between business hours and non business hours). schedule tasks run continuously, but your function if-statement only runs during your defined business hours. Here running at 1minute interval (testing odd vs even minutes), you can spec your own business hours:

```
import datetime as dt
import schedule, time
from datetime import datetime

def printJob():
    week = dt.datetime.today().weekday()
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
    if week < 5 and datetime.now().minute % 2 ==0:  # in range(9,17):
        print(f"business hours test...EVEN minutes... {timestamp}\n")
        # your business hours function here...
    else:
        print(f'go home...test... ODD minutes... {timestamp}\n')

schedule.every(1).minute.do(printJob)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```